# How much health does the tank have?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

In some waves of the Mann vs Machine gamemode, a tank slowly rumbles towards you to deliver its own bomb.  How much damage does it take to destroy this monstrosity?

Comment: We must find out for Science!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The health of Tanks is not fixed, it is based on the current mission and wave. This is defined within `*.pop` files in `\tf\scripts\population`.

- Mannworks

  - Mission 1

    - Wave 2: **20,000**
    - Wave 7: **22,500** x2
  - Mission 2

    - Wave 4: **18,000** x2
    - Wave 7: **18,000** x2, **20,000** x2
  - Mission 3

    - Wave 1: **18,000** x2
    - Wave 3: **20,000** x2
- Coal Town

  - Mission 1

    - Wave 3: **28,000**
    - Wave 4: **30,000**
    - Wave 6: **33,000**
  - Mission 2

    - Wave 2: **30,000**
    - Wave 5: **25,000** x2
    - Wave 7: **20,000** x2, **35,000** x1
  - Mission 3

    - Wave 4: **35,000**
    - Wave 6: **30,000** x1, **20,000** x2
- Decoy

  - Mission 1

    - Wave 3: **20,000**
    - Wave 8: **20,000**
  - Mission 2

    - Wave 6: **25,000**
    - Wave 8: **25,000** x2
  - Mission 3

    - Wave 4: **25,000** x2
    - Wave 6: **32,000** x1, **30,000** x2

Info about `*.pop` files: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2884318